# How to find the corresponding x value for a given y value in a plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I now have a plot and a given y value. I would like to find the corresponding x value for the given y value = 209. I tried to use the code here:

```
x = np.interp(209, ydata, xdata)
```

But this code doesn't work and always gives me the maximum x value which means nothing.

What should I do for finding the corresponding x value? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def find_x(val, xdata, ydata):
    x = np.where(ydata==val)
    return int(xdata[x])
```

INPUT:

```
xdata = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
ydata = np.array([2,4,6,8,10])

print(find_x(4, xdata, ydata))
```

OUTPUT:

```
3
```