# What's the best way to extract the x coordinate for a given y value in a plot using Python?

Tags: python, opensees

I have the following graph:

[image]

Being Uplot the x axis and Pplot the y axis, when doing

```
peakPplot =  np.max(Pplot)
Uplot_peak = np. interp(peakPplot, Pplot, Uplot)
print(Uplot_peak)
```

When I used this instead
[How to find the corresponding x value for a given y value in a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785885/how-to-find-the-corresponding-x-value-for-a-given-y-value-in-a-plot)
I could only get the first value

Uplot_peak reported the last value within y but it is outside the graph as it is in shown

Finding the corresponding x value for a given y value within a graph

Comment: Just to clarify: for a given value of y, you want all values x (hence an array) where f(x)=y ? With f being the plotted function